# How to go to definition for a module in agda on vsc

Tags: visual-studio, agda, go-to-definition

In visual studio code, the go to definition doesn't work for agda modules. I checked the key-bindings for agda-mode and the only one useful seemed `c-c c-o` but that doesn't seem to find some loaded modules and gives

```
Panic: Unbound name:
Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.Core.erefl[0,2,4,6,30]@ModuleNameHash
6189151057044369179
when retrieving the contents of a module
```

error message. And in many instances it would be helpful to find a definition for just a function instead of the whole module.

Comment: Have you tried using the middle button of your mouse ?

Comment: @MrO It didn't work